# Fostex FR-2 DC plug/connector

Tags: fostex, battery, powering, connector

Using AA batteries to power the FR2 doesn't cut it for me anymore. For some time now I've been looking for a solution using a RC battery pack with a tamiya connection and make a tamiya to DC cable. Quite a simple procedure, however I just can't seem to find the model of the DC connector that fits into the FR-2. I've tried all the different DC plugs I have around the house, nothing fits. I've been searching the internet for the correct model to the point of pulling my hair out, still no luck. I don't have the FR2 AC mains adapter otherwise I would cut the connector from that. Can anyone help me identify the DC connector?

Here's a photo of the left side panel of the FR2:
http://www.inquitaudio.co.uk/assets/images/fr2left-2.jpg

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, there are dozens if DC connectors like that, but they all slighty differ in connector size and voltage so it may be near impossible to know for sure. However, I know some FR2 users who got their units modified with a Hirose connector in order to run NP1s and other such outside power sources.

Comment: @stavrosound I was afraid that might be the case. Yes i've come across the hirose modification on the web when searching for a solution. It seems like it might be the best, but i dont feel comfortable doing a mod like this myself. Thanks for the response however. 

Answer (score 1):

you could ask [hawkswood](http://www.hawkwoods.com/products/details/details.php?code=npr-fr2&mainMenuItemToSlide=5&asi=np-70&asi2=mr4) where they get there plugs from, as they build the NP1 solutions for FR2, which uses the same plug. I use the tamiya batteries with the fostex cable, but those cables are really hard to come by now a days. It's a shame because the tamiya battery solution is such a great idea and works really nicely.

Comment: @RedSonic01 It's worth a try. Yes i've seen the cable from fostex, called 8570 is my memory serves me well. A bit too pricey at €50 for such a simple cable. Thats the reason i want to make my own, which can be done for just a few euros. Hunting down this cable is my last resort if i dont find the correct connector. However the other thing thats confusing me is dat i've seen pictures of fr2 units which seem to have a different DC in than the one i linked to. They have a metal pin in the center instead of the center hole. I'm wondering which plug the 8570 cable uses. 

Comment: I'll check when I get home but I am pretty sure that it is the metal pin in the centre type. Yes it is a weird plug. btw have you tried looking for one on bblist.co.uk? might be worth putting an advert there for an old fr2 power unit or something similar.

Comment: @RedSonic01 thanks, i appreciate that. I dont want to sound rude, but any chance you could make a close-up photo of the plug? I would certainly help me find it. Either way thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Martin - sorry it took so long for the photos but been a bit busy at work ;) hope the link works - http://www.flickr.com/photos/55848647@N06/sets/72157632617893706/
If not I can try again -

Comment: @RedSonic01 no problem, thanks alot for the photos!

Answer (score 0):

@pezzatronic I had same problem and modified mine, bringing out a little cable with an in-line RCA connector.